# Ejecutar proyecto flutter Xcode, problema de permisos

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

comento estoy intentando ejecutar un proyecto de Flutter con un dispositivo físico Apple o emulando con Xcode, pues me da los errores que adjunto en las capturas, he realizado consejos de todo tipo he incluso he desinstalado por completo y vuelto a instalar Xcode con la guía de la web de Flutter, y nada, la cuestión es que antes funcionaba perfectamente, pero hacía unos meses que no emulaba ni utilizaba dispositivos de Apple y ha habido actualizaciones de Xcode que si actualicé. Os paso las captura, llevo ya tres días intentando solucionar este problema, parece fácil por ser un problema de permiso pero nada los directorios tienen atribuido los permisos pertinentes.
Nada he actualizado y nada es un problema de permiso con xCode **"Couldn't create workspace arena folder '...... ': You don’t have permission to save the file “Runner-.......” in the folder “DerivedData”.** Pero no se como solucinarlo

[image: resultado de la ejecución flutter doctor]

[image: errores que me tira]

Comment: Segun los mensajes pareciera ser que no tienes permiso de escritura sobre la ruta que se indica (iniciada como `/Volumes/NVMe_128Gb/diegofdez/Library/...`). Es una unidad de disco especial? solo lectura, de otro usuario?

Comment: Concuerdo con el primer comentario, al parecer no tienes permisos sobre una carpeta que se indica en los logs. Pero también recuerda que para instalar en un device real tienes que aceptar ciertos permisos ( en el iPhone) y seleccionar una cuenta de developer al momento de hacer build

Comment: Es el disco de sistema, y tengo privilegio como administrador, pero nada cuando ejecuto sudo Flutter run, tampoco me funciona y me da una alerta que no debe ejecutar comando Flutter como root

Comment: Intentaste en otra ubicación como en el Escritorio o Documentos? Revisaste en la documentación de Flutter si soporta la nueva versión de Xcode?

Comment: en lugar de editar la pregunta con un "solucionado", ¡añade respuesta con la explicación completa! Mira [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) para más info

Comment: Ok, no lo sabía, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné el problema de la siguiente forma:

Hice un cambio ubicación de la carpeta de usuario en Mac a otro disco. Aunque realicé la operación con el comando `sudo ditto -rsrcFork -V`, debía de configurar en Xcode en preferencias la localización de los archivos requerido para Xcode funcione.

En mi caso, estaban apuntando a una dirección exacta y ahora está en defecto: esto garantizará que cuando mueva el archivo de usuario a otro lado no tendré este problema pues le pasa los parámetro un archivo que está en la carpeta de usuario.

Para configurar Xcode correctamente debes entrar en el menú superior *Xcode->Preferencias->localización->* cambias las direcciones a por defecto.